# Created API for twitter to display latest 5 posts

Tags: php, javascript

is there created API for twitter to display latest 5 posts for non-wordpress website? I got website coded in php/html/css (without cms), and I need to add twitter box, where there is shown latest 5 tweets, from user. Is there any created API for this already?

Comment: *(If you vote the question down, leave a comment.)* Please explain a bit further what you're after — a javascript widget? I'm almost certain that `API` is not the term you're looking for (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding you, but if you're just looking for a simple widget that displays a Twitter user's most recent tweets, you can use Twitter's own profile widget for websites.

The link is [here](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile). You can customize the appearance and settings of it to match your website's design.

Otherwise, if you're looking to do that all yourself, look at minitech's link for the Twitter API documention. One API I've used successfully for posting/retrieving tweets with PHP is called twitter-php, which you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-php/).

Cheers,

~Berserkguard

Comment: Thank you ;)! I was searhcing for the default one ;)! I'll accept as answer in 4 minutes. Happy new year ;)!

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy new years to you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Twitter API can be found at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api. You can find data for any user in JSON format.